# Bootstrap 5 Scrollspy taking id from url and scroll to the specific section with the id

Tags: bootstrap-5, scrollto, scrollspy

I'm using **bootstrap 5 Scrollspy** to navigate into different sections of my home page. It works fine when I click on the navigation link (E.g, projects). The url becomes: `https://example.com/#projects` and scroll to that section.

HTML:

```
<body data-bs-spy="scroll" data-bs-target="#navbar-main" data-bs-offset="240">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav ms-md-auto mb-2 mb-lg-0 fixed-top">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#about">About</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#services">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
             <a class="nav-link" href="#projects">Projects</a>
         </li>
                                    
     </ul>
     <main>
        <section id="about"> ...</section>
        <section id="services"> ...</section>
        <section id="projects"> ...</section>
    </main>

</body>
```

But When I'm refreshing or using the same URL in the address bar and load the page it doesn't scroll to that section. So How can I achieve the behavior of taking the #id from the url and scrolling to that section??

*[Note: I'm using `body{overflow-y: hidden}` and showing a splash screen for say 5 seconds when a  user loads the page for the first time then resetting back to `overflow: auto`]*

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `id="navbar-main"` on your `<ul>` that corresponds to `data-bs-target="#navbar-main"`.